# .htaccess redirect won't execute a specific file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect custom urls to my customtimer.php page and for some reason it doesn't work.

According to the code below, I'm trying to catch all website.com/u/username (with or without trailing "/") and execute the website.com/customtimer.php?un=$1 page but somehow it doesn't work (i get sent to 404 page). I've tried so many combinations that i'm baffled. The errordocs redirects lower down work just fine...

What am i missing?

```
RewriteEngine on

# make sure that all common folders wont be interpreted as timers
RewriteRule ^(admin|css|images|js|mlb|nba|nfl|nhl|php|templates|wav)/?(.*) - [L]

# redirect to the right user page or direct-url timer
RewriteRule ^/u/(.+?)/?$ /customtimer.php?un=$1 [NC,L]

# some error catching, lets give users more beautiful pages to look at (ja)
ErrorDocument 400 /400-badrequest.php
ErrorDocument 401 /401-authreqd.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403-forbid.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404-notfound.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500-server.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `leading slash` from 2nd rule and tweak your regex a bit:

```
# some error catching, lets give users more beautiful pages to look at (ja)
ErrorDocument 400 /400-badrequest.php
ErrorDocument 401 /401-authreqd.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403-forbid.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404-notfound.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500-server.php

RewriteEngine on

# make sure that all common folders wont be interpreted as timers
RewriteRule ^(admin|css|images|js|mlb|nba|nfl|nhl|php|templates|wav)/? - [L]

# redirect to the right user page or direct-url timer
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]+)/?$ /customtimer.php?un=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Also make sure to place above .htaccess in your `DocumentRoot` directory

**EDIT: joel**

As anubhava said just before this, it was discovered that the problem came from editing the .htaccess file from the root/ of the server instead of where the root/html/ folder where the web files were. Therefore the .htaccess file could not run the request. To fix the problem, a copy of .htaccess was uploaded to root/html/.htaccess and now it works perfectly..

Comment: thanks for the help. it still doesnt work. The strange thing is that if i type website.com/jkhgfkjhgfdkjg it sends me to my 404 page fine, but when i type website.com/u/test it doesn't send me to 404 but not the page i want either... it sends me to what seem like my index.php home page without the CSS...

Comment: ok no my bad, it was sending to 404 page, but under /u/ because the 404 redirect above didnt have http://website.com/404-notfound.php , which i just fixed. So in another word, it doesnt redirect at all

Comment: ok... htaccess was in root/ instead of root/html that was it. i didnt know you had to copy that file to the html folder. Do i need to copy the htaccess in all sub folders??

Comment: Not needed, it will work fine from `/html` folder as that is `DocumentRoot` for your site.